# Error after integrating facebook API in ios App in xcode4.3.2

Tags: ios

I faced errors when integrated facebook api in my application the errors details below:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_StatusViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

StatusViewController is my viewContoller class where I used facebook API classes what ever recomodated by facebook developer site . can any one guide me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means in the file ViewController you are obviously accessing StatusViewController but have not imported it in ViewController .h or .m file:

in ViewControllers .h file put:

```
       #import "StatusViewController.h"
```

Comment: when I am going to use the StatusViewController in other class (means wants to create a object) it shows this error .